# Forcing string interpolation in Jade

Tags: internationalization, pug

I am trying to use Jade to do some string interpolation + i18n

I wrote a custom tag

```
mixin unsubscribe
   a(title='unsubscribe_link', href='#{target_address}/', 
     target='_blank', style='color:#00b2e2;text-decoration:none;')
   = __("Click here")
```

Then I got the following to work

```
p
  | #[+unsubscribe] to unsubscribe
```

However, in order to support i18n I would also like to wrap the the whole string in a translation block the function is called with `__()`.

But when I wrap the string in a code block it no longer renders the custom tag.

```
p
  | #{__("#[+unsubscribe] to unsubscribe")}

p
  = __("#[+unsubscribe] to unsubscribe")
```

will output literally `[+unsubscribe] to unsubscribe`. Is there a way to force the returned string from the function?

**Edit 1**

As has been pointed out, nesting the `"Click here"` doesn't really make sense, since it will be creating separate strings.

My goal with all this is really to create a simplified text string that can be passed off to a translation service:

So ideally it should be:

`"#[+unsubscribe('Click here')] to unsubscribe"`

and I would get back

`"Klicken Sie #[+unsubscribe hier] um Ihr auszutragen"`

My reasoning for this is that because using something like gettext will match by exact strings, I would like to abstract out all the logic behind the tag.

Comment: You've already wrapped `__("Click here")`. You should only pass plain strings to the i18n function. Passing whole jade block wouldn't make sense. Rendering the entire jade string (to html) is always the last step, after all the function calls (including your i18n transformation) have been done.

Comment: @laggingreflex You are correct, I actually wanted to have "Click here" inlined so that it would show up as an inlined string (I'll fix my example). The problem with passing just plain text is that it creates several strings that then would appear out of context to a translator.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to achieve is this:

```
<p>
  <a href='the link' title='it should also be translated!' 
     target='_blank' class='classes are better'>Click here</a> to unsubscribe
</p>
```

And for some reason you don't want to include tags in the translation. Well, unfortunately separating 'Click here' from 'to unsubscribe' will result in incorrect translations for some languages - the translator needs a context. So it is better to use the tag.

And by the way: things like `__('Click here')` doesn't allow for different translation of the string based on context. I have no idea what translation tool you're using, but it should definitely use identifiers rather than English texts.

Going back to your original question, I believe you can use parametrized mixin to do it:

```
mixin unsubscribe(title, target_address, click_here, to_unsubscribe)
  a(title=title, href=target_address, target='_blank', style='color:#00b2e2;text-decoration:none;')= click_here
    span= to_unsubscribe
```

This of course will result in additional `<span>` tag and it still does not solve the real issue (separating "Click here" from "to unsubscribe") and no way to re-order this sentence, but... I guess the only valid option would be to have interpolation built-in into translation engine and writing out unescaped tag. Otherwise you'd need to redesign the page to avoid link inside the sentence.

Comment: I may have been too vague on what my goal is. You're right the click here should not be in the custom tag. Ideally I want to pass something like: `"[+unsubscribe Click here] to unsubscrbe"` to a translator so that I might get back `"Klicken Sie [+unsubscribe hier] um Ihr auszutragen"`. Since the replacement is by exact match I want to minimize lookup fails because the details of the link changed.